# Else statement is not showing any result

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am executing a query where I am checking item_id from the table (cart). When I am checking the result using if and else condition then else condition doesn't give any response.

```
 begin
  statement = Connection.conn.prepare("SELECT item_id from cart where item_id IN (?) ")
  result3 = statement.execute(input_id)
  result3.each do |row|
    if ( row["item_id"] == input_id )
      puts 'Already in cart'
      puts row["item_id"]
    else
      puts 'Added to cart'
      puts row["item_id"]
    end
  end
rescue Exception => e    
  puts "#{e.message}"
  puts "#{e.backtrace.inspect}"
  Connection.conn.close
end
```

Comment: You explicitly select only rows with `item_id` ≡ `input_id`, with this query `else` condition would never met.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ never rescue `Exception`, rescue what might be thrown.

Comment: then how should I execute it?

Comment: One of [Ryan Davis' "Quick Tips"](http://www.zenspider.com/ruby/quickref.html) is, "Don’t rescue `Exception`. EVER. or I will stab you." Shubham, you want a specific error class, such as `ArgumentError`, `TypeError`, and so on, depending on the type of error you want to rescue.

Comment: I cannot read your mind and I have zero idea about the business logic behind.

Comment: I have changed the Exception to TypeError...but still else statement is not executing

Comment: I m trying to check cart if item_id already existed in the cart or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions in your SQL statement and your Ruby code iterating over the result set are mutually exclusive.

Let's say the `cart` table contains the following items:

- `item_id: a`
- `item_id: b`
- `item_id: c`

You execute this statement

```
statement = Connection.conn.prepare("SELECT item_id from cart where item_id IN (?) ")
result3 = statement.execute(input_id)
```

in a context where `input_id` is a specific value that you obtained somehow. It can be any value. `a`, `b`, `c`, potentially something that doesn't exist in your database like `z` or `x`.

Assuming that the `item_id` is unique in the table, your query will return a result set that will contain 1 element (if the value of `input_id` is `a`, `b` or `c`) or 0 elements (if `input_id` is anything else). `result3` will be empty or it will have one element whose `item_id` is the same as `input_id`. The query literally transpates to *Give me the cart item whose `item_id` is `<whatever the value of input_id happens to be>`*

At runtime, we're looking at two potential scenarios. Let's start with an empty result set (no elements with the given `input_id` have been found)

```
result3.each do |row|
   # your code
end
```

does nothing because there are no elements in `result3`.

The only other thing you can get is an array with a cart item with the `item_id` of `a`, `b` or `c`, depending on what you passed as `input_id`.

In this case, the `else` condition is never met

```
[{'item_id' => 'a'}].each do |row|
    if ( row["item_id"] == 'a' ) # Always true because the item in the result set was selected by its index, 'a'
        puts 'Already in cart'
        puts row["item_id"]
    else
        puts 'Added to cart'
        puts row["item_id"]
    end
end
```

This logic is flawed. What you seem to be trying to do is to check if an item with a given id already exists in the `cart` table and add an element to the table if it doesn't. A `SELECT` statement will never do that. This looks like a job for an [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) statement. SQL is a very powerful language on its own. If you find it confusing, you could have a look at [Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) which abstracts it away, hiding the database behind an object-oriented facade. I haven't done any database programming in Ruby in ages so I'm not sure what's cool these days.

Comment: Thank you very much, It really helped me a lot.